# .NET Library for CGM File Conversion

Tags: .net, converters, .net-3.5

I have been working on a utility to convert  various files to PDF for easy printing/emailing.  I'm trying to add support for CGM files but have not been able to find any libraries to help me do so.

Is this something that I can possibly do natively within C#?  Or are there any .NET based libraries that could help me convert CGM files?

Answer (score 2):

#### JCGM

Using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net) you could pull in the Java [JCGM](http://jcgm.sf.net) library.

It has support for rendering to a Java Graphics object and no dependencies on other libraries. I'm not sure if IKVM will support all the required Swing calls but its definitely got support for some: [AWT/Swing a Little Bit Less Unsupported](http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=e8206772-da68-4753-bb05-1ff5e4a90a8d)

Answer (score 1):

At a past employer, we used the LIB_CGM library from SDI quite a bit:

http://www.sdicgm.com/cgm_output_library.html

This was written in C - so although it isn't native .NET you should be able to use it from C# as an unmanaged extension.

Google also came up with another C implementation:

http://www.cgmlarson.com/industry/cgm_generator_library.php

I found CGM a pain - it is one of those formats that has a lot of vendor or industry specific extensions. I was in the geophysics/seismic industry, where CGM was still being used a lot but with extensions! As CGM seems to be mainly used in industry specific applications (eg. CGM+ in the seismic industry), I suspect  vendors are more interested in C applications that are readily cross-platform rather than PC-only solutions (eg. .NET). Users typically want to use their third party libraries on everything from big iron supercomputers to desktops (although we actively kept plotting functionality off the supercomputers!).