# .NET or C# library for CGM (Computer Graphics Metafile) format?

Tags: .net

Does anyone know a .NET C# library for displaying CGM files in WinForms and Microsoft Service Reports/CrystalReports so that it is printable as well?

It would also be extremely helpful if it is also able to convert the file to a web-friendly graphics format like jpeg, gif, png etc.

This is likely a repeated question from [.NET Library for CGM File Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205596/net-library-for-cgm-file-conversion) but that OP did not mark an answer nor were the suggested solutions .NET compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to share this temporary hack with SO. I still need a proper library if possible (Credit goes to everyone who makes .NET excel tutorials available online):

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CGM

{
    public class CGMConverter 
    {
        Image _mImage;

        public Image Image { get { return _mImage; } }

        public CGMConverter(string cgm, float width, float height)
        {
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Excel.Application xlsApp = null;
            Excel.Workbook xlsWorkBook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet xlsWorkSheet = null;

            try
            {
                xlsApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                xlsWorkBook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlsWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlsWorkBook.Sheets["sheet1"];
                xlsWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(cgm, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 50, 50, width, height);
                xlsWorkSheet.Shapes.Item(0).Copy();
                _mImage = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
            finally
            {
                xlsApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                xlsApp.Quit();
                releaseObject(xlsWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlsWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlsApp);
            }
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a non-temporary hacky solution for this? I tried just putting it in, but it doesn't seem to show the image, just says "This image cannot currently be displayed."