# Convert .CGM file to JPG or PNG using c#?

Tags: c#, cgm

I am trying to convert ".cgm file to .jpg or .bmp file" in c# but nothing is working for me. I can convert .cgm file to .pdf and then .pdf to .jpg or .bmp.

Is there any way to convert directly from .cgm to .jpg? If yes then how?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but did you look at these?:

Excel as a workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813481/net-or-c-sharp-library-for-cgm-computer-graphics-metafile-format

IKVM to use a java library:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205596/net-library-for-cgm-file-conversion

Comment: i read this link but not able to understand what they want to do?

Comment: It would help if you provided a link to a sample file you want to read. It also seems someone made CGM# project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cgmsharp/

Comment: The post is from 2016, but it could still be visited by someone searching for similar conversions. If using a professional library is an option, these conversions can be made directly using [LEADTOOLS SDKs](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats#vector). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). To try that, there’s a [free evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).